# C# Selenium very different execution time everytime

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using threading to run multiple chromedrivers. I'm currently optimizing my app. I found out that my simple methods execution time is always different and I don't know why.

```
   public bool IsAccountBanned()
    {
        try
        {
             w.Start();
             
            const string text = "#__layout > div > div > div.base-main.flex.flex-column > div.empty-wrap.flex.flex-column.align-center.justify-center.flex-auto > p";
            bool exists = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(text)).Displayed;
            
            Debug.WriteLine(w.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

            if(exists)
            {
                LogAdder.AddLog("Removed banned account", manaIndex, true);
                return true;
            } 
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("falsing" + w.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            return false; 
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

Output in debug looks like this

```
falsing:2683
falsing:511
404
falsing:3271
falsing:318
falsing:149
```

Why is times of finding element so different? From 150ms up to 3270ms. All bots are on same page with same content

Can anyone explain to me why is it happening please or if there is any fix for it? Thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: The amount of time it takes varies due to a large number of factors: 1) Network latency between your test and the selenium server; 2) Network latency between the browser being automated and the web server; 3) Processes currently running on the test machine; 4) Processes currently running on the web server... the list goes on and on. You will need to profile the application, including the web application, in order to determine where speed problems are.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Network latency has nothing to do with how long it takes to click a button on screen and Selenium is run locally so there not connection to a "Selenium server".

Comment: Even when Selenium runs locally, there is a server - the server resides on your computer. This means your tests and the Selenium server (and the browser) are subject to performance issues on your computer. Alternately, the page might be getting hung up waiting for some elements to load or waiting for the page load event. My best advice is to make sure you are using the correct version of ChromeDriver based on the Chrome version. Sometimes that helps. Chrome likes to auto-update.

Comment: You're right actually, ignore my previous comment. Might be good for you to write an answer including the info from your second comment.